syncfusion ejs-richtexteditor ampersand problem
When entering an ampersand '&' into the text field, the cursor unexpectedly moves to the start of the line instead of maintaining its current position.
HTML:
<div class="wrap" [style]="'--defaultHeight:' + height + 'px'">
  <ejs-richtexteditor
    #rteElement
    id="rte"
    appEmptyStringToNullValue
    [ngClass]="smallToolbar ? 'small-toolbar' : 'default-toolbar'"
    [locale]="locale"
    [toolbarSettings]="tools"
    [pasteCleanupSettings]="pasteCleanupSettings"
    [height]="height"
    [width]="width"
    [formControl]="providedControl"
    [fontFamily]="fontFamily"
    [saveInterval]="100"
    [title]=" required ? ('requiterFieldTooltip' | translate) : ''"
    (created)="rteCreated()"
    (afterPasteCleanup)="toggleEdit(true)"
    (beforeDialogClose)="toggleEdit(true)"
    (beforeDialogOpen)="toggleEdit(false)"
    (actionBegin)="actionBegin($event)"
    (change)="onChange($event)"
  >
  </ejs-richtexteditor>
  <div class="error" *ngIf="!acceptedLength">{{'charactersExceededError' | translate}}</div>
</div>

.ts file:
export class RichTextEditorInterComponent extends DestroyableDirective implements OnChanges, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('rteElement') public rteObj: RichTextEditorComponent;

  @Input() public providedControl: FormControl = new FormControl();

  @Input() public width: number | string = '100%';

  @Input() public maxLength: number = RTE_DEFAULT_MAX_LENGTH;

  @Input() public required = false;

  @Input() tools = RTE_TOOLS;

  @Input() fontFamily: FontFamilyModel = RTE_FONTS;

  @Input() showToolbar = true;

  @Input() disableEnter = false;

  @Input() smallToolbar = false;

  @Input() pasteCleanupSettings: object = PASTE_CLEANUP_DEFAULT_SETTINGS;

  @Input() placeholderFocusedKey = null;

  @Input() placeholderUnfocusedKey = null;

  @Output() public lengthError = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  @Output() public valueChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();

  @Input()
  public get height(): number | string {
    return this._height;
  }

  public set height(height: number | string) {
    this._height = height || 'auto';
    this.rteObj?.refresh();
  }

  public ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (this.smallToolbar && changes?.showToolbar) {
      this.setToolbarVisibility(changes.showToolbar.currentValue);
    }
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.validateContentLength();
  }

  public getTextInputValue(): string {
    return this.rteObj.getText();
  }

  public setToolbarVisibility(value: boolean): void {
    if (!this.rteObj) return;

    if (value) {
      this.rteObj.toolbarSettings.enable = true;
      this.rteObj.placeholder = this.placeholderFocusedKey
        ? this.translatePipe.transform(this.placeholderFocusedKey)
        : null;
    } else {
      this.rteObj.toolbarSettings.enable = false;
      this.rteObj.placeholder = this.placeholderUnfocusedKey
        ? this.translatePipe.transform(this.placeholderUnfocusedKey)
        : null;
    }
  }

  public rteCreated(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setToolbarVisibility(this.showToolbar);
      this.rteObj.refreshUI();
    }, 0);
  }

  public toggleEdit(isAllow: boolean): void {
    this.canEdit = isAllow;
  }

  public onChange({ value }: ChangeEventArgs): void {
    if (this.canEdit) {
      this.providedControl.setValue(value, {
        emitEvent: false,
      });
      this.valueChanged.emit(this.providedControl.value);
    }
  }

  public actionBegin($event: any): void {
    if (this.disableEnter && $event.requestType === EditorAction.EnterAction) {
      $event.cancel = true;
    }
  }

  private validateContentLength(): void {
    this.providedControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(startWith(this.providedControl.value), takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe$))
      .subscribe((value) => {
        if (value) {
          this.acceptedLength = value?.length < this.maxLength;
          this.lengthError.emit();
        } else {
          this.acceptedLength = true;
        }

        this.lengthError.emit(!this.acceptedLength);
        this.rteObj.updateValue(value);
      });
  }
}

Problem can be caused by any of these methods, but i cannot find it out. It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
